# Photo permissions in Facebook Graph Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-like

Why can I not like this [photo](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3611605126197&set=a.3561005581240.193812.1155834080&type=3&theater) through the Graph Explorer? I can do it using a browser, but then I tried to POST a like through the Graph API Explorer and I got `false` as the response.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/3611605126197/likes
```

For some reason the Graph Explorer works different than the browser. Why? I know it is a private person photo album, but still it is possible to like this photo using the browser so there must be a way to like it using the Graph Explorer.

Comment: i post this query https://graph.facebook.com/3611605126197/likes. To like my foto this query is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. If you are not friends with the individual you cannot grab the photos via the API. `friend_photos` are for your friends only. You may be able to see it on your personal Facebook account but not the same level of privacy is transferred across using the API.

You *can* however see Facebook page photos, just not personal profiles.